# Postgres HStore - Updating existing columns with values from Hstore

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I am trying to move data from a HStore to a Column using the following query

```
update mytable set "height" = tags->"height" , 
"building:levels" = tags->"building:levels", "type" = tags->"type", 
"building:part" = tags->"building:part" 
Where ( tags->"building:levels" <>'' or "tags"->"height" <> '' 
or "tags"->"type" <> '' or "tags"->"building:part" <> '' );
```

The idea was to try and speed the query up by testing for non null values in the HStore. (This is a very large database)

After two days of the query running, I am sure there must be a better way. This is my first attempt at moving data form HStore into a Column.

I can see `populate_record` in the documentation, but cannot figure out how to use it to just get the hstore tags I need to the correct columns.

Is my original syntax correct and is there any way I can do it faster using `populate_record` and if so, what should the query look like?

Many Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get an error? Does it not update the values as you expect it to? Is it too slow?

Comment: Question Updated, too slow and is my syntax correct, Thanks

Comment: Do you really have a column named `"building:levels"`? Using column names that require quoting isn't usually a good idea. How many rows are you updating through this statement? If you are updating most of the rows then there is hardly any way to speed this up. If only a few rows qualify in the `where` condition adding an index on the `tags` column and using the hstore exists operator ( `?`) to find rows with the keys might speed up things The key value for the `->` operator should be string literal `'height'` not an identifier (`"height"` is an identifier, e.g. a column name)

Comment: Yes, inherited database schema with the ":" in the filed name., I totally agree, it is a pain. Million+ rows. Copy on key value. Thanks. Am adding an Index now, it is a small percentage of the database, so that might help. Thanks

Comment: You might not be needing the update at all if you index your hstore column. Simple read access `tags -> 'height'` (e.g in the select list) isn't that much slower than accessing a column value. If the hstore is indexed then using a condition on the hstore ( `where tags ? 'height'` or `where tags -> 'height' = '42'`) is probably just as fast as using a `where` condition on the "replicated" (and indexed) column. Plus you don't need the additional index(es) on the replicated columns so in total you have _less_ indexes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The Index did the trick, thanks, please post as an answer and I will mark as Correct.